# C# wpf open new window form list combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, window

Help me.
I want to open any window in a combobox list. This is the code I use when opening an existing window.

```
windowname wdname = new windowname();
                wdname.ShowDialog();
```

But now I have a window list. I want to open a window when I select in combobox.
What should I do.
Thanks so much for help.

Comment: I guess you aren't using *MVVM* and want to do this in *code behind*. Look up the `ComboBox` help, and find the changed or selected item event

Comment: oh. i want windowname = combobox.text when i combobox select. but I don't know how to declare the correct command. EX: combobox.text wdname = new combobox.text();
                wdname.ShowDialog();

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener for `SelectionChanged` event and handle user selection.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBoxSelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="UsersWindow">Users Window</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="SettingsWindow">Settings Window</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="CustomersWindow">Customers Window</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Code-behind

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public List<Window> Windows { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Windows = new List<Window>
        {
            new Window { Name = "UsersWindow" },
            new Window { Name = "SettingsWindow" },
            new Window { Name = "CustomersWindow" },
        };
    }        

    private void ComboBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = (ComboBox)e.Source;

        if (comboBox.SelectedItem == null) return;

        var selectedItem = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox.SelectedItem;
        var window = Windows.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Name.Equals(selectedItem.Tag));

        if (window == null) return;

        window.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help
In case I want to declare a string for the name of the window, how do I do it?
Like:
   string windowname = combobox.text;
   windowname wdname = new windowname;
   wdname.ShowDialog ()
Can you help me.

Comment: Are you want set string name for the window in XAML?

Comment: i want call name of window by string, string is combobox selecteditem.